# What's the default frame rate for a timeline?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-2, timeline

Timeline has a [constructor for setting a target frame rate](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html#Timeline%28double%29), and an empty one for (presumably) using some default value.

However, the docs don't seem to state a value as to what the default is - what is it?

Answer (score 3):

> [By default, an Animation's framerate is not explicitly limited,
>   meaning the Animation will run at an optimal framerate for the
>   underlying platform.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#getTargetFramerate%28%29)

Comment: This probably means that this value can vary depending on which platform the application is running. I agree with that.

Comment: Yup, sorry I should have pointed out I read this bit, but wanted to actually know what value it was defaulting to at least on my particular system.

Comment: The current implementation of JavaFX targets render pulses at 60fps, so it makes sense that animations would not attempt to exceed that rate (extra animation frame computations would be worthless). However, it's quite believable that future releases might increase that rate.

Comment: Sure - they key part there for me is that the rate is only likely to increase in future. For one particular rather simple animation I'm doing (just scrolling a notice) this takes up a rather large amount of CPU on a machine that hasn't got an FX supported graphics card, and setting it down to something like 25 doesn't produce much of a noticeable visual difference, but does take up far less resources. Of course, JFX8 has better support for graphics cards anyway so perhaps that will be less of an issue when that's finally released!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find out the answer from the docs, but the default Timeline constructor in the source delegates straight to the default [Animation constructor](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/openjfx-rt/src/469a4e88a8077845898f41a817ad3d4907fd9065/javafx-anim/src/javafx/animation/Animation.java), which specifies it as the following:

```
this.targetFramerate = TickCalculation.TICKS_PER_SECOND / ToolkitAccessor.getMasterTimer().getDefaultResolution();
```

At present, at least on 7u51 on Windows, `TICKS_PER_SECOND` is set at 6000 and `ToolkitAccessor.getMasterTimer().getDefaultResolution();` yields 100, **giving a default framerate of 60.**

It should be noted however that this is just pulled from the source and is subject to change - so this should just be used as a rough guide rather than *relying* on the default value always being 60.